# fopen return null while file exists

Tags: windows, cygwin, fopen

I am developing a lexer for F++ language using Cygwin terminal and flex tools on Windows 8 OS.

The problem I met and I am having hard time to solve is the case of multiple input buffers.

Let's say I have an F++ file with a #include test.h header. My lexer then have to open the
test.h file and recognize its tokens before it proceeds to the file etc.

My lexer uses fopen function to open header files but fopen returns null even if my file exists.

I quote my code.

```
**<incl>[ \t]*      /* eat the whitespace */
 <incl>[^ \t\n]+   { /* got the include file name */
    if ( include_stack_ptr >= MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Includes nested too deeply" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    include_stack[include_stack_ptr++] =YY_CURRENT_BUFFER;

    if( (yyin = fopen( yytext, "r,ccs=ccs=UTF-8")) !=NULL)
    {
        printf("Successful opening %s in mode r.\n",yytext);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file %s in mode r.\n",yytext);
    }

    yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ) );
    printf("testpoint4");
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    printf("testpoint5");
    }
    <<EOF>> {
    if ( (include_stack_ptr--)==0 ){
    printf("here");
    yyterminate();
    }else{
    printf("edw2");
    yy_delete_buffer( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER );
    yy_switch_to_buffer(include_stack[include_stack_ptr] );
        }
    }

%%
main()
{ yylex(); }**
```

Comment: LOOK at your code. In particular, look at the second parameter to `fopen` and compare it to the documented acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

Check the line: fopen( yytext, "r,ccs=ccs=UTF-8")

use a filename that does not have a comma in it.

for an abundance of caution, try a trivial file name, like foo.fpp

if the file opens, the problem is in the permitted characters for files on your filesystem/OS.